# CSS: Element with Lazy Width

Tags: css

Let's say that I want to make a `<p>` element that has a fixed height and a width that only grows if the height is not sufficient to display all of the text. By default, `<p>` is a block level element. This means it has a greedy width and lazy height. I want the opposite, lazy dynamic width and fixed/greedy height. An inline-block element tries to display the text in one line if possible, which is not something I want. I want a pure CSS solution just because. Is it possible?

Comment: That's kind of hard to conceive of because text isn't written vertically. So the `p` would have to start out with at least a minimum width....(so the text will be forced to wrap inside some minimum width). I'm thinking you might have better luck in telling us what you are trying to achieve, rather than how this impossible element would help you achieve it.

Comment: I can see that a funky element like this some uses, but I, myself, just want to do it because I can. Or if you want another way of stating my goal, I am testing the limits of the this language.

Comment: Congratulations. Limit reached. I can envision a bunch of hacks that will all have failing edge cases involving transforms.....listen to @Oriol's great answer (directly from the spec), it can't be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.

> [**9.4.2 Inline formatting contexts**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-formatting)
>
> In an inline formatting context, boxes are laid out horizontally
>   [...]. The rectangular area that contains the boxes that form a line
>   is called a *line box*.
>
> The width of a line box is determined by a [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#containing-block) and the
>   presence of floats. [...]
>
> In general, the left edge of a line box touches the left edge of its
>   containing block and the right edge touches the right edge of its
>   containing block. However, floating boxes may come between the
>   containing block edge and the line box edge. Thus, although line boxes
>   in the same inline formatting context generally have the same width
>   (that of the containing block), they may vary in width if available
>   horizontal space is reduced due to [floats](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats). [...]
>
> Line boxes are created as needed to hold inline-level content within
>   an inline formatting context. [...]

Therefore, the width of the line boxes will only be affected by the width of the containing block and the presence of floats. And then, there will be as many line boxes as necessary.